# Popover getting closed when I am selecting dropdown inside it

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is JavaScript code to bind the popover. When I select the dropdown option it automatically get closed, and it is not selecting any element inside the dropdown.

```js
$("[data-toggle=popoverGroupByEmp3]")
  .popover({
    datahtml: true,
    html: true,
    'title': 'Salary payble account code',
    content: function() {
      var iD = $(this).attr('data-Id');
      return $(".jvAccountCode").html();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12 hidden jvAccountCode">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddl_AccountCode", (List
    <SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lstAccountCode, "Select account code", new { @class = "form-control selectpickerddl" })
  </div>
  <div class="popover-footer pull-right">
    <button id="close-popover" data-toggle="clickover" onclick="$('[data-toggle=popoverGroupByEmp3]').popover('hide');" type="button" class="btn btn-default popover-cancel">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary popover-submit">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is HTML that I am using in MVC.

Comment: your example is not working, you should fix it

Comment: Include the popover script tag